# How can I share the same interface for an async and synchronous methods?

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, interface, win-universal-app

I am currently working on 2 applications, a .NET 2.0 winforms application and a UWP app. Most of the classes are shared in both applications.

I have an interface called `IDialogService` that has a concrete class specific for .NET2 and another concrete class for UWP. `IDialogService` exposes a method called `ShowDialogYesNo()` that returns a `boolean` depending on what the user clicked.

The problem is that the `MessageDialog` in UWP has a `ShowAsync` method instead of just a synchronous `Show` method. So I won't be able to use the same signature for showing a `MessageBox` or a `MessageDialog`.

Some of the classes that are shared to both projects use an instance of an `IDialogService`. But since the UWP version of showing dialog needs to be `async`, I can't use the `ShowDialogYesNo()` method from `IDialogService`.

We use dependency injection to inject .NET2 or UWP instance to the constructor. My goal here is to **not** have a different code base for .NET2 and UWP.

It will only differ in the concrete class implementation of the interface for every platform. I also don't want to have a bunch of `#if WINDOWS_UWP` in my code if that's possible.

Here's the code:

```
  public interface IDialogService
  {
    bool ShowDialogYesNo();
  }

  public class DialogServiceNet2 : IDialogService
  {
    public bool ShowDialogYesNo()
    {
      var result = MessageBox.Show("DialogMessage", "", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1, MessageBoxOptions.DefaultDesktopOnly);
      if (result == DialogResult.Yes)
        return true;
      return false;
    }
  }


 public class DialogServiceUwp : IDialogService
  {
    public bool ShowDialogYesNo()
    {
      //????
    }
  }
```

This class is originally in the .NET2 project then I added it as a link to the UWP project. So it's basically the same file.

```
  public class SomeSharedUtil
  {
    IDialogService _commonDialog;
    public SomeSharedUtil(IDialogService commonDialog)
    {
      _commonDialog = commonDialog;
    }

    public bool AskUser()
    {
      return _commonDialog.ShowDialogYesNo();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't.  An asynchronous operation requires a different public API than a synchronous method.  The *caller* needs to call synchronous and asynchronous operations differently (unless it's a fire and forget method) so two types *can't* fulfill the same contract (a.k.a. interface) if one is only synchronous and one is only asynchronous.

Comment: You're right, I'm just trying my luck. I would probably stick to using #if WINDOWS_UWP if I really want to have the same code.